# Using ionic translate item as a variable

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-translate

I am new in Ionic framework and I want to use translate item as variable in `ng-if` condition. The `{{ "country" | translate }}` displays a value to my page but I want to use this value in the below condition.

`<div ng-if="country=='my country'">
      This is my country
</div>`

But I don't how to use this,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ionic translation in **If Statement**:

```
<div ng-if="('country'|translate) == 'afghanistan'">
  This is Afghanistan
</div>
```